# Visual C++ Migration from visual studio 2008 tfs to 2010 tfs and from net framework 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have a visual c++ project in visual studio 2008 and NET Framework 3.5. Now, I have migrated into visual studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4.0.

Once converted, I see that some external dependencies (*.h files) have been added automatically to a new folder created 'external dependencies' also created automatically. All the files *.h in this folder are referenced to a relative path:

c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\atlmfc\include\

And I do not understand because in visual studio 2008 and net framework 3.5 this folder, external dependencies, does not exist.

Why this folder is created automatically and populated with a lot of *.h files?

Also, each time a get latest is performed from team foundation server, this project always appears marked as checked-out. why?

Comment: If you're using .NET, it's not C++. C++/CLI, possibly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'external dependencies' is a new feature of VS2010.  It is a virtual folder containing all the header files intellisense has found that your code depends on.  If you don't find it useful it can be disabled (which is what I do) from Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->Disabled External Dependancies set True.